# sort list of integers that are value to a key in dictionary python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, key-value

i have a 300 frames from a video in format name_numberofFrame, i created a dictionary with key as name and value to key as list of number of frame but this list is not sorted i want it to be sorted to perform some other operations.
please provide me a way to sort that list?

Comment: You can access each value and sort it, it's not that difficult a thing to do.

a={'a':[4,2,1], 'v':[41,5,1]}

for i,j in a.items():
    a[i]=sorted(a[i])
    
a gives you, {'a': [1, 2, 4], 'v': [1, 5, 41]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that difficult. You can access each value inside this dictionary and sort it. Like this:

```
a={'a':[4,2,1], 'v':[41,5,1]}

for i,j in a.items():
    a[i]=sorted(a[i])

print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 4], 'v': [1, 5, 41]}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Providing answers to bad questions encourages the asking of bad questions. If the Q  is not fixed, Q&A will be deletet most probably so your time is wasted.

Comment: Haha, I just wanted to help the guy. He is new. And I did post on comments but it was not in proper coded order. I am fine it being deleted. I understand your point too.

At least he will get an answer. I did search around, and couldn't find any answer to his question being already answered. It's fine to help at times I believe.

Comment: I personally believe if people can lead him to a helping answer as a duplicate and not just mark his question as bad, it would help him better. This way just marking the question as bad, neither he got an answer, nor he understood why it was bad.